# How can I resolve this "illegal start of expression" error?

Tags: java

```
public void cariData(){
     if(!= dataPasienview.getTextCari().getText().trim().isEmpty()){
         dataPasienimpl.getCariData(dataPasienview.getTextCari().getText());
         isiTableCariData();
     } else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dataPasienview, "silahkan pilih data");
     } 
}
```

Comment: `if(!= ...)` you're missing an argument...

Comment: @alfasin as the right expression is a boolean (isEmpty()), I suppose the = should simply be removed.

Comment: @dystroy I guess you're right! (it's the worst if condition I've seen for a while...) +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `=` after the `!` :

```
if(!dataPasienview.getTextCari().getText().trim().isEmpty()){
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, change != to just !

You should also reverse the test.
Statements like

```
if (!x) { 
    doSomething(); 
} else { 
    doErrorThing();
}
```

will trip up static code analysis tools as being confusing. It's easier to read as

```
if (x) { 
    doErrorThing(); 
} else { 
    doSomething(); 
}
```

Comment: I disagree. It feels natural to first put the normal path, that is the not empty text.

Comment: PMD (a very common static analysis tool) disagrees with you :) see the "ConfusingTernary" entry at http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/java/pmd/rules/design.html